# How can I use a modal correctly in my case (inside a class)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

I want to use a modal inside my react-native application. I've watched some videos and even read the react-native website about modals but they use hooks everywhere like the following:

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
```

My problem is, that I am inside of a class and it is not possible to use a hook inside of a class. So my question is: how can I use exactly this functionality but without using a hook?
Heres my modal:

```
<Modal visible={modalVisible} animationType = "slide">
  <View style={StyleSheet.modalContent}>
    <Button title = "close" onPress = {() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}/>
    <Text>inside the modal</Text>
  </View>
</Modal>
<Button title = "show more" onPress = {() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}/>
```

I am very very thankful for every helpful answer! :)

Comment: React docs on [converting a function to a class](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class). Start here to learn how the two types of components can be used to accomplish the same thing. Next look at [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for how to replace the hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, after hours of googling I found something that works well for me, [here it is](https://dev.to/bhuma08/react-create-modal-using-class-components-5d1g).